# Where is the Application Support folder if your App is on a external hard drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, logic

I have downloaded Logic Pro 10.6.3, but since it is almost 2 GB I moved it to my 2TB external hard drive.

I need to access to Application Support to install plug-in's, but I cannot the support folder for Logic Pro.

I am running macOS Big Sur, on a 13" MacBook Pro.

Comment: By default it will be in the same place as if the app was in /Applications so in your home directory

Comment: RE: "but I cannot the support folder for Logic Pro" --  Please clarify this.  -- That said, the **Application Support** _folder_ for the **User Domain** in in your **Home** _folder_ at **~/Library/Application Support** regardless of where the _application_ is installed/run from.

Comment: Have a look at [How to move Logic’s additional content to a secondary drive](https://www.logicprohelp.com/move-logics-additional-content-secondary-drive/) and [Logic Pros: Relocating and organizing your Sound Library in LPX 10.5](https://9to5mac.com/2020/08/30/move-logic-pro-sound-library/).